# /r after every word

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

So, I am creaing a "Hangman" game, with a word editor to put your own word in the game. I have a form which opens a text file and displays the content in a multi-line textbox. After that the user can edit the textbox. If you press "save" the content from the textbox will be saved to the text file.

Now, everything works good, the reading and the writing. But now if I want to play my words, its always longer than the word I entered. I found out via debugging that somehow my programm adds "/r" behind every word. For example if I enter "Test" in the wordeditor, the game would use it as "Test/r".
I believe it is an error in the wordeditor so here is the code:

```
namespace Hangman
{
  public partial class WordEditor : Form
  {
    public WordEditor()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:\\Users\\tstadler\\Desktop\\Hangman.txt", FileMode.Open)))
      {
        string[] Lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        {
          textBox1.Text += Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine;               
        }
      }     
    }

private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
      FileStream overwrite = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\tstadler\\Desktop\\Hangman.txt", FileMode.Create);
      using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(overwrite))
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
          file.Write(words[i] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
      }

  MessageBox.Show("Words saved. ");
}
```

Can anyone tell me if he recognizes the error? 
Thanks.

Comment: + Environment.NewLine;     will add a /r

Comment: it stands for  carriage return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everywhere you insert new lines you use `Environment.NewLine` - except for one line:

```
string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
```

Which results in a string splitted by `\n` whereas `Environment.NewLine` consists of `\r\n` on a Windows system. Thus after the split the `\r`remains at the end of  the string.

To resolve that issue simple replace the line mentioned above with

```
string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine });
```

Comment: that gives an error. "The best overloaded method for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments."

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler sorry, thanks for pointing that out - I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx):

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the file:
>
> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return `\r`, a line feed `\n`, or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed.

and [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx):

> Creates a new file, write the specified string array to the file, and then closes the file.

sample:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filePath");

File.WriteAllLines("filePath", textBox.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almosut correct but very verbose look at this:

[File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx);

and

[File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=VS.80%29.aspx);

so your read section would be:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
       File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
```

and write

```
 File.WriteAllText(filePath,textBox1.Text);
```